# Elastica filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

I am testing out Elastica and Elastic Search. I am trying to add a filter to my query that only returns results by city location. It is returning empty. I've tried filter by username, and so on and it always returns empty, so it would seem my understanding isn't quite correct. Here's my code to analyse, map, then search with a filter

```
    $elasticaIndex = $elasticaClient->getIndex('users');
    // Create the index new
    $elasticaIndex->create(
            array(
        'analysis' => array(
            'analyzer' => array(
                'indexAnalyzer' => array(
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'filter' => array('lowercase', 'lb_ngram')
                ),
                'searchAnalyzer' => array(
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'filter' => array('standard', 'lowercase', 'lb_ngram')
                )
            ),
            'filter' => array(
                'lb_ngram' => array(
                    "max_gram" => 10,
                    "min_gram" => 1,
                    "type" => "nGram"
                )
            )
        )
            ), true
    );
    //Create a type
    $elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType('profile');


    // Set mapping
    $mapping->setProperties(array(
        //'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'include_in_all' => FALSE),
        'firstName' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE),
        'lastName' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE),
        'username' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE),
        'bio' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE),
        'thumbnail' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => FALSE),
        'location' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE),
    ));
```

..... Then to search, I do the following

```
        $elasticaQueryString = new Elastica\Query\QueryString();

        //'And' or 'Or' default : 'Or'
        $elasticaQueryString->setDefaultOperator('AND');
        $elasticaQueryString->setQuery($term);

        // Create the actual search object with some data.
        $elasticaQuery = new Elastica\Query();
        $elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);
```

To add a filter

```
            $elasticaFilterLocation = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
            //search 'location' = $region;
            $elasticaFilterLocation->setTerm('location', $region);           
            $elasticaQuery->setFilter($elasticaFilterLocation);
            $elasticaResultSet = $elasticaIndex->search($elasticaQuery);                
            $elasticaResults = $elasticaResultSet->getResults();
```

If I comment out the filter, I do get the expected results. What am I missing? Does it have to do with the analyzer or mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by changing my analyzers for these fields in the mappings. Now I have to rebuild my indexes etc... Don't try to find a solution to change mapping or analyzer without rebuilding your index, you can't.

```
lc_analyzer' => array(
   'type' => 'custom',
   'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
   'filter' => array('lowercase')
),
```

For mapping:

```
'location' => array('type' => 'string', 'analyzer' => 'lc_analyzer'),
```

Then, query like

```
 $elasticaFilterBool = new \Elastica\Filter\Bool();                
 $filter1 = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
 $filter1->setTerm('location', array(strtolower($region)));                
 $elasticaFilterBool->addMust($filter1);
 $elasticaQuery->setFilter($elasticaFilterBool);
```

I think your location is being tokenized on spaces and commas so it is killing the search. should solve it for you.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Such as what you changed your analyzer from and what you changed it to?

Comment: I used 2 custom analyzers 1 for email, tokenizer: uax_url_email, and another for words (like your location case), tokenizer: standard, did some stuff by trial and error as there are not a lot of documentation... Tell me if you need help

Comment: yes, please help. I am spinning my wheels here getting nowhere. The documentation is very sparse. I have tried using tokenizer: standard for location and have rebuilt my index but it still returns empty.

Comment: {"index.analysis.analyzer.e_analyzer.tokenizer":"uax_url_email","index.analysis.analyzer.e_analyzer.type":"custom","index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.type":"custom","index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.tokenizer":"standard","index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.filter.1":"lowercase","index.compression":"true","index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.filter.0":"standard","index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.filter.2":"asciifolding"}

Try this as your index settings, then in your mapping set the analyzer for the location field to location_analyzer, tell me if good

Comment: Since I am using Elastica, I translated the above like so: 'location_analyzer' => array(
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                        'filter' => array('standard', 'lowercase', 'asciifolding')
                    ),

'location' => array('type' => 'string',  "analyzer" => "location_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer" => "location_analyzer"),

Rebuilt index, tried again. Still nothing.

Comment: I think it should be good: try curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index_name/_settings to see if the settings are the same like me, and curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/index_name/type_name/_mapping to see if the mapping worked fine

Comment: curl -XGET localhost:9200/offers/_settings shows this
"index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.tokenizer":"standard",
"index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.type":"custom",
"index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.filter.0":"standard",
"index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.filter.1":"lowercase",
"index.analysis.analyzer.location_analyzer.filter.2":"asciifolding",

and curl -XGET localhost:9200/offers/offer/_mapping shows this:
"location":{"type":"string","analyzer":"location_analyzer"},

So it looks ok, right? But empty result.

Comment: Yes right I guess you have to do it by trial and error. Like try maybe to change tokenizer to whitespace put in an entry and test a search... Can you show me a location string example

Comment: I use these filters on $region variable. $region is something like "Toronto, ON"
$elasticaFilterLocation = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
                //search 'location' = $region;
                $elasticaFilterLocation->setTerm('location', $region); 
                $elasticaFilterOr->addFilter($elasticaFilterLocation);
                $elasticaFilterAnd->addFilter($elasticaFilterOr);
                $elasticaQuery->setFilter($elasticaFilterLocation);

Comment: I am out of ideas, i am sure you are on the good way but don't know what small thing we're missing. Checkout this post it may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836642/analyzers-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. I will keep trying and post a solution if I get it.

Comment: Try with simple queries though not like the code you showed in a comment :) will let you know if I come up with something

Comment: hey, was still working on my project and faced another issue similar as yours, with the same mapping and everything provided above, some queries were returning empty results in elastica, but when I searched for them in terminal curl they were working fine, so what I tried is that I used querystring in elastica, I added the code up there in case you want to try. hope it helps.

Comment: I think we are close. If I search "Starbucks" without your suggestion, it returns two results. If I then apply the filter it returns ALL items that match location : Toronto, ON. To make this work, I think I need to apply the filter to the subset of results from "Starbucks". Am I right? If so, how would I do that? In your code, you run the search on $elasticaType, what is that?

Comment: $elasticaIndex = $elasticaClient->getIndex('index_name');
$elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType('type_name');

Comment: I updated the code, I think this is what you want if you replace field and value

Comment: I am a little confused. I am getting an error "query produced is invalid". $queryString = '{ "query": { "filtered" : { "query" : {  "query_string" : { "query" : "term : starbucks" }}}, "filter":{"location:Toronto, ON"}}}'; causes the error. I've tried various combinations but I think I am just misunderstanding. Can you clarify by updating this $queryString?

Comment: I am not a pro, I am learning while doing my work, but I think querystring should be something like this: { "query": {
              "filtered" : {
         "query" : {
                      "query_string" : {
                 "query" : "term:starbucks",
                      }
                  },
         "filter" : {
                      "term" : { "location":"Toronto, ON" }
                  }
              }
          }
      }

Comment: no luck, with the same error. it seems like we are so close but just missing something small.

Comment: no error, but not quite filtering. the query will return results for Toronto, ON even though the query is for Halifax, NS
'{ "query": { "filtered" : { "query" : {  "query_string" : { "query" : "location:Halifax, NS"}}, "filter":{"term":{"title":"starbucks"}}}}}'

Comment: If I replace "location:Halifax, NS" with "location:Toronto, ON" then it returns only the Toronto Starbucks. Very weird!

Comment: @landland Your clarifications should be in the question. They don't belong in the comments. Codebird: same thing.  Please update your question with the clarifications, and your answer with the same.