# Why I can retrieve records in Elastic search using bool query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've inserted a record in ElasticSearch an I can see that here:
[image: Elastic Search Bool Query]

But this query returns nothing:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "name": "Ehsanl"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I post this query using `post` method to this user: `http://127.0.0.1:9200/mydb/customers2/_search`
What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the name as "ehsanl". All in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

What you see on your screenshot is the original document as you indexed it (`_source` field).

However, by default, string fields are analyzed (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836642/analyzers-in-elasticsearch/12846637#12846637) for more detail about analysis).

Using [standard](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html#analysis-standard-analyzer) analyzer, your name value should have been lowercased to `ehsanl` and stored this way in the index : `term` queries search for the exact value `Ehsanl` in the index, which doesn't exist.

You can either :

- use `ehsanl` value with `term` query
- use `Ehsanl` value with a `match` query, which will apply the same analyzer before to search.