# Guide line for indexing data with Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I have gone through a small article for how to index data using Lucene.Net but few code meaning was not clear to me those are

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("ID", oData.ID.ToString() + "_" + oData.Type, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Title", oData.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Description", oData.Description, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.Add(new Field("Url", oData.Url, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
writer.AddDocument(doc);
```

What is the meaning of this line `doc.Add(new Field("ID", oData.ID.ToString() + "_" + oData.Type, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));`

What is the meaning of `Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED and Field.Index.TOKENIZED`

if possible please discuss about the importance of these words in details `UN_TOKENIZED and Field.Index.TOKENIZED`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucene has deprecated `TOKENIZED` and `UN_TOKENIZED`, they're now named `ANALYZED` and `NOT_ANALYZED`.

The meaning of `NOT_ANALYZED` is, that the fields contents will **not** be run through an analyzer. In effect they're considered a single 'term' if searched. As an example for where this is useful the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html) names unique product ids (i.e. [EANs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Article_Number) or [UPCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code)).

The meaning of `ANALYZED` means that the fields contents will be analyzed and (possibly) be broken down into more than one 'term'. The Lucene documentation mentions this is useful for common text. The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483903/comparison-of-lucene-analyzers) explains some commonly used analyzers very well.

For further reference please also refer to the [Lucene.net](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/annotated.html) and [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_1/index.html) documentations.