# How to search full text in lucene 4.10

Tags: java, lucene

I want to search text phase in pdf like "Labor Law". But in result, it return all file that contain the word "Labor" and "Law". please any help checking my cod below:

```
EnglishAnalyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer();
analyzer.setVersion(Version.LATEST);          

QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("content", analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse("Labor Law");

Directory indexDirectory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexLucencePath));
DirectoryReader dirReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDirectory);
indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(dirReader);

ScoreDoc[] queryResults = indexSearcher.search(query, numOfResults).scoreDocs;

List<IndexItem> results = new ArrayList<IndexItem>();
for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : queryResults) {
    Document doc = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
    results.add(new IndexItem(doc.get(IndexItem.TITLE), doc.get(IndexItem.CONTENT)));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

Phrase query:

```
Query query = parser.parse("\"Labor Law\"");
```

All terms must be present

```
Query query = parser.parse("+Labor +Law");
```

You can also create query yourself like this

```
BooleanQuery query= new BooleanQuery();
TermQuery clause1 = new TermQuery(new Term("content", "Labor"));
TermQuery clause2 = new TermQuery(new Term("content", "Law"));
query.add(new BooleanClause(clause1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
query.add(new BooleanClause(clause1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
```

Comment: Your solution will search 2 words the content file. but i want to search the phrase "labor law", not "labor" and "law".

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of Analyzer available, please check with different Analyzer for your requirement. [Comparison of Lucene Analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483903/comparison-of-lucene-analyzers). This may also help [Lucene: Multi-word phrases as search terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066347/lucene-multi-word-phrases-as-search-terms)

Comment: what is the suitable Analyzers with my case?