# Does examine index search (Umbraco) support words with accents?

Tags: umbraco, examine, umbraco-ucommerce

I am using Examine index search of Umbraco to search Ucommerce products. If I search for Loreal, it works fine. But when I search for L’Oréal, it gives me 500 error.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What's the 500 you get? Maybe you can take a look at what analyzers should be used?

This sounds like a lucene problem with the way that your index are created and what fields are analyzed and how.
[Comparison of Lucene Analyzers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483903/comparison-of-lucene-analyzers)

Comment: I mean it is not taking the accents in words. L’Oréal has accents and it gives 500 error